# pygame not filled shapes (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, draw

If I want to craw a circle, I use the regualr draw.circle but the problem is that I don't want it filled so I draw a smaller circle inside of it, it makes a circle with thickness.

Everything is good right? no. The background image inside that circle disappeared because the circles are filled.

***Now my question is: There is a function that draws a circle (and other shapes[?]) that gets thick and not filling the whole inside of the shape?***

EDIT: If you can give me the signature so I know how to use it.

Comment: `pygame.draw.*` will be empty if width is zero. If the quality isn't good enough, you could draw using sprites, or vectors.

Comment: Can you give me the signature?
What are the parameters of pygame.draw.* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is `pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0)`.  The last argument of width can be changed to not fill the circle in.  If it is zero, the circle is solid and if it is anything else it is with an edge thickness of whatever the parameter is.

Comment: Why there are missing pixels that aren't in color?

Comment: @Ofek Do you mean in the center of the circle or around the edges of it?

Comment: I did it with the width but in places in where which should be colored it's isn't.

Comment: It might be just that you are making the width really small.  Try setting it to 10 or so.

Comment: But I NEED it in width of 25, when I do it with draws it's ok.

Comment: make sure your radius is more than 50 or the center won't be big enough for you to see it

Comment: I'm still not sure what could be happening.  Show me the code and I might be able to figure it out.